# AttributeError: type object 'BST' has no attribute 'contains'

Tags: python, tree, binary-search-tree, nodes, attributeerror

I keep getting the attribute error, that BST does not contain the attribute contains when it does, this is a simple BST program to check if a node contains a subtree.

I'm new to python so I don't know what is the issue here, any help would be appreciated.

```py
from collections import namedtuple


class BST:
    #We are using namedtuple since it allows us to create an object with names for each position
      tuple = namedtuple('tuple', ['left', 'right', 'value'])



#here, contains is a static method since we have to create a utility function to check 
#if the node has the value in its subtrees.

@staticmethod
def contains(root, value):
      if root.value == value:
          return True
        
     #means the value is greater than the root node and must lie on the right sub-tree.
      elif root.value < value:
            
            #if the right subtree is empty, than the said node does not contain the value, return false.
          if root.right == None:
               return False
            
            
            
           #it does contain a right subtree, recursively call the contains method again till you find the value.
          else:
               return BST.contains(root.right,value)
            
     #else,root value is lesser than the root node and must lie on the left side.
      else:
            
        
        
        #if the left subtree is empty, than the said node does not contain the value, return false.
          if root.left == None:
              return False
          else:
              return BST.contains(root.left,value)
         


n1 = BST.tuple(value=1, left=None, right=None)
n3 = BST.tuple(value=3, left=None, right=None)
n2 = BST.tuple(value=2, left=n1, right=n3)



result= BST.contains(n2, 3)
print (result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your static method is wrongly indented. In Python, as there are no braces to signify where a class ends, any indentation that is on the same level as the first part of Python code after class definition is considered a part of that class.

Indent you static method like this, and it will work:

```py
class BST:
    #We are using namedtuple since it allows us to create an object with names for each position
    tuple = namedtuple('tuple', ['left', 'right', 'value'])



    #here, contains is a static method since we have to create a utility function to check 
    #if the node has the value in its subtrees.
    @staticmethod
    def contains(root, value):
        ....
```

P.S. I would recommend against using `tuple` as the name of an attribute of your class, as that is a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-tuple) and should be always available (not overshadowed by something else in the namespace).